# field type for unix timestamp

Tags: sql

Whats the best field type to use for unix timestamps?

Will `int(10)` be enough for a while?

Comment: What database are you using?  And wouldn't you use a native datetime data type?

Answer (score 79):

[Unix `time_t`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is either 32 bits wide, or 64.  So, `int(8)` or `binary(8)` is sufficient, at least for the next 293 billion years.

Comment: Please be aware that `int(8)` does not always do what this answer suggests it does; [bobince's answer has an explanation.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1993585/2014893)

Answer (score 16):

The number in a MySQL `INT(n)` datatype doesn't specify how much storage space is reserved, it's a display-width for formatting purposes only. As such an `INT(10)` is the same as a plain `INTEGER`, that is to say a 32-bit signed number.

So this is certainly an appropriate datatype for a 32-bit Unix timestamp. But if you want 64-bit timestamps it's not going to be enough; you would have to use a `BIGINT`.

Answer (score 7):

For Unix timestamp you can easily use `INT(4) UNSIGNED` which max value is `4294967295`. It's far enough for you to store `time()` values for the next ~133 years. If your app will stop working because of this, you will be long dead ;)

You can also try to use TIMESTAMP data type, which is less problematic and when you want to convert it to Unix timestamp you can use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function.

ex.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(col_timestamp) FROM tbl_name;
```

Comment: int(4) here (4) is just display width so if number is 13 it will display like 0013. And display width is deprecated in MySQL 8 and will be removed. Use only int rather than int(x) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58938358/mysql-warning-1681-integer-display-width-is-deprecated

Comment: "If your app will stop working because of this, you will be long dead ;)" Ahahaha))) lol

Answer (score 3):

For timestamps, you should use the `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` field type.

Comment: However, this puts you at the mercy of the database and access layer for date types and string representations, which can make writing cross-environment applications more difficult. It is often simpler and more expedient to use plain integers whose behaviour is totally predictable, where there aren't other date types in the database against which you hope to compare.

Comment: @Megaman: no. Timestamp is just a datatype, it doesn't have any such special behaviour.

Comment: @Megaman: MySQL timestamp columns only update on record updates **when** you've set a DEFAULT constraint using the `ON UPDATE` clause.  This is the second time in the last few days I've seen people talk of the misunderstanding.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: MySQL `TIMESTAMP` behavior is complex, and easy to misunderstand, IMHO.  In 5.0, the first such column in a field is automagical if it *lacks* a `DEFAULT` and `ON UPDATE` specifier -- they're silently implied/applied -- and behavior was different in previous versions.  These misunderstandings are unlikely to die down any time soon...

Comment: @TatuUlmanen [you almost certainly don't want `TIMESTAMP`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860351/mysql-column-type-timestamp-implicitly-includes-not-null-default-current-time).