# Current Boolean column data type best practice in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have the following pseudo-table I want to create in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE 'Stuff' (
  'ID' bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'IsAThing' boolean NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('ID')
)
```

As of now (v8.0.x), MySQL doesn't actually have a boolean data type for this and instead, I need to use a `TinyInt`. In the past, best practice was to use `TinyInt(1)`, where the `(1)` part isn't so much a data type but a default display configuration (i.e. only display 1 digit of the TinyInt number, even if it was storing the value 100).

However, these days, doing this gives you a warning that Integer display width is deprecated. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58938358/mysql-warning-1681-integer-display-width-is-deprecated) is related but more specifically addresses the use of `INT(4)`. The recommendation there is to either use `INT` or to ignore the warnings. In that case, I think I would opt to just use `INT` but my question is more specific to the boolean-equivalent usage.

What is the best practice for this boolean-like data type? Should I just use `TINYINT` instead of `TINYINT(1)`, given that the feature is now deprecated? Or should I be doing something different? My goal is to not use deprecated features for this new database that will likely live for years through future DB upgrades.

Comment: I think you will find that there has never been a boolean really it has always been a tinyint

Comment: in our shop, we consistently represent boolean as `TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED COMMENT 'boolean, ...'` and if we don't allow NULL values, then we add `NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'` ... lots of other ways to do it, we just do it like that for consistency.  if we start getting problems using the `(1)` length specifier, then we will just drop that, and continue ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display with doesn't really matter. Just use `TINYINT`. MySQL does have `BOOLEAN` and you can totally use that as well. It's simply the same thing as `TINYINT`.

Comment: A lot of connectors automatically convert TINYINT(1) to BOOLEAN and TINYINT to an INT or SIGNED BYTE.  This deprecation is going to break a lot of things